# Calculate (x,y) from (Lat,Lon) in a cropped equirectangular projection

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, projection

I have a **piece of a map** in **equirectangular** projection. I know (lat,lon) in left-top and bottom-right positions. Now I know I can calculate (x,y) like this:

```
x = ((lon + 180) * (map_width  / 360))
y = (((lat * -1) + 90) * (map_height  / 180))
```

However, it seems that this produces wrong coordinates. My guess is that I have to take into account the left-top and bottom-right (lat,lon) for my image.

So I tried this way (where left, top, right, bottom_lon respresent my image boundaries):

```
x = ((lon + left_lon) * (map_width  / (right_lon - left_lon)))
y = (((lat * -1) + top_lat) * (map_height  / (top_lat - bottom_lat)))
```

But I still don't get the right result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question with these two Python functions:

```
def lon2x(lon, w):
    return int(img_w * ((lon - start_lon) / (end_lon - start_lon)))

def lat2y(lat, h):
    return int(img_h * ((lat - start_lat) / (end_lat - start_lat)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer, it is forgotten that subtracting from height. So, it must be like this:

```
def lon2x(lon, w):
    return int(img_w * ((lon - start_lon) / (end_lon - start_lon)))

def lat2y(lat, h):
    return int(img_h) - int(img_h * ((lat - start_lat) / (end_lat - start_lat)))
```

**Edit**: They are approximate correct results, but for the **very accurate** results, you should use the **projection method** whatever used to creating map (like Mercator or Equirectangular).